# XNA soundEffect is null in when loaded in main class and called in another class

Tags: c#, xna

I have loaded a sound effect file into the main class in xna, but when I try to run it in another class I am given this error

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

I am new to XNA classes so I do not really understand them. Any help as soon as possible is greatly appreciated.

this is part of the main class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace BreakingOut
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Ball ball;
    Paddle paddle;
    Rectangle screenRectangle;
    bool is1P = true;

    int lives = 3;

    Texture2D startButtonTexture;
    Vector2 buttonVec;

    Texture2D exitButtonTexture;
    Vector2 button2Vec;

    int bricksWide = 10;
    int bricksHigh = 7;
    Texture2D brickImage;
    Brick[,] bricks;

    //rec for menu
    Texture2D menuTexture;
    Rectangle menuRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 960, 640);
    //rec for pause
    Texture2D pauseTexture;
    Rectangle pauseRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 960, 640);
    //lose
    Texture2D loseTexture;
    Rectangle loseRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 960, 640);

    Texture2D winTexture;
    Rectangle winRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 960, 640);

    //sound effects
    public  SoundEffect BallHitSE;
    SoundEffect WallHitSE;
    SoundEffect StartSE;
    //BGM
    Song menuMusic;
    Song gameMusic;

    bool isGameMusicPlaying = false;
    bool isMenuMusicPlaying = false;

    float pauseTimer;
    float exitTimer;
    float muteTimer;
    float SEmuteTimer;

    //public int brickCount = 70;

    SpriteFont font;

    Vector2 mousePos;

    enum gameStates
    {
        MENU,
        GAME1P,
        LOSE,
        PAUSE,
        WIN,
    }

    gameStates currentState = gameStates.MENU;
    gameStates prevState = gameStates.MENU;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        IsMouseVisible = true;

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 960;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 640;

        screenRectangle = new Rectangle(
            0,
            0,
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth,
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Texture2D tempTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddle");
        paddle = new Paddle(tempTexture, screenRectangle);

        BallHitSE = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("BallHit");
        WallHitSE = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("WallHit2");
        StartSE = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Start");
        gameMusic = Content.Load<Song>("gameMusic");
        menuMusic = Content.Load<Song>("menuMusic");
```

This is the Ball class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace BreakingOut
{
class Ball
{
    Vector2 motion;
    Vector2 position;
    Rectangle bounds;
    bool collided;

    public int brickCount = 70;

    const float ballStartSpeed = 6.4f;
    public float ballSpeed;

    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle screenBounds;


    SoundEffect BallHitSE;
    //BallHitSE = new SoundEffect

    public Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get 
        {
            bounds.X = (int)position.X;
            bounds.Y = (int)position.Y;
            return bounds;
        }
    }

    public Ball(Texture2D texture, Rectangle screenBounds)
    {
        bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, texture.Width, texture.Height);
        this.texture = texture;
        this.screenBounds = screenBounds;
        //Different things we tried
        //BallHitSE = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("BallHit");
        //BallHitSE =  new soundeffect(what goes in here?);
        //BallHitSE = Content.Manager.Load("path")

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        collided = false;
        position += motion * ballSpeed;
        ballSpeed += 0.001f;

        CheckWallCollision();
    }

    public void CheckWallCollision()
    {
        if (position.X < 0)
        {
            position.X = 0;
            motion.X *= -1;
            //if (BallHitSE != null)
            //{
                BallHitSE.Play();
            //}
        }
        if (position.X + texture.Width > screenBounds.Width)
        {
            position.X = screenBounds.Width - texture.Width;
            motion.X *= -1;
            //if (BallHitSE != null)
            //{
                BallHitSE.Play();
            //}
        }
        if (position.Y < 0)
        {
            position.Y = 0;
            motion.Y *= -1;
            //if (BallHitSE != null)
            //{
                BallHitSE.Play();
            //}
        }
    }

    public void SetInStartPosition(Rectangle paddleLocation)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        motion = new Vector2(rand.Next(2, 6), -rand.Next(2, 6));
        motion.Normalize();

        ballSpeed = ballStartSpeed;

        position.Y = paddleLocation.Y - texture.Height;
        position.X = paddleLocation.X + (paddleLocation.Width - texture.Width) / 2;
    }

    public bool OffBottom()
    {
        if (position.Y > screenBounds.Height)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void PaddleCollision(Rectangle paddleLocation)
    {
        Rectangle ballLocation = new Rectangle(
            (int)position.X,
            (int)position.Y,
            texture.Width,
            texture.Height);

        if (paddleLocation.Intersects(ballLocation))
        {
            position.Y = paddleLocation.Y - texture.Height;
            motion.Y *= -1;
        }
    }

    public void Deflection(Brick brick)
    {
        if (!collided)
        {
            motion.Y *= -1;
            collided = true;
            brickCount -= 1;
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var drawPosition = position - (i * motion * 3);
            var colour = Color.Lerp(Color.White, Color.Transparent, i * (20 / 100f));
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, drawPosition, colour);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Colton has the answer for you, but I think you should at first try to get a general idea of how classes work in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user Kai Hartmann solved this question with an easy and simple fix

> Make sure, Ball is instantiated before LoadContent().
>
> Then swap this line
>
> BallHitSE = Content.Load("BallHit"); with this
>
> Ball.BallHitSE = Content.Load("BallHit"); and change the
>   variable in your Ball class to this
>
> public static SoundEffect BallHitSE;

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/66184/36332

Answer (score 1):

XNA classes are no different than a regular class, don't let them fool you!

It seems you just need to set the two pieces equal to eachother.

In the ball class:

```
public Ball(Texture2D texture, Rectangle screenBounds, SoundEffect ballHit/*NEW*/)
{
    this.BallHitSE = ballHit;// NEW

    bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, texture.Width, texture.Height);
    this.texture = texture;
    this.screenBounds = screenBounds;
    //Different things we tried
    //BallHitSE = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("BallHit");
    //BallHitSE =  new soundeffect(what goes in here?);
    //BallHitSE = Content.Manager.Load("path")

}
```

Then just add the sound effect to the constructor:

```
 Ball ball = new Ball(texture, bounds, BallHitSE);
```

Comment: Is the error still the same? Also, I don't think it would make a difference, but make sure you are loading the effect before sending it to Ball.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I ran through the code when it first happened to check it. I also tried putting if null into it to try and bypass it but it only stopped it from crashing

Answer (score 1):

If you use those `SoundEffect` in your `Ball` class you shoud load them in the `LoadContent` of your `Ball` class, not in the main class.
That's why you receive that error when you try to run one of it, they are initialized in another class and are still null.

Of course if you have to load something in `Ball` class you need to pass the `ContentManager`, or make that `Ball` class inherits from `GameComponent` or `DrawableGameComponent`, in order to load your sound effects in this way:

```cs
BallHitSE = Game.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("BallHit");
WallHitSE = Game.Content.Load<SoundEffect>("WallHit2");
```

**EDIT**

Usually I manage audio in this way:

```
public class AudioComponent : GameComponent
{
    public enum LevelEffect { BadCollision, GoodCollision, PopUp }
    public enum GameMusic { GameWin, GameLose, GameStart }

    private Song winSound, loseSound, startSound;
    private SoundEffect badCollSound, goodCollSound, popUp;

    public AudioComponent()
    {
    }


    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }


    public void loadAudio(
        Song winSound,
        Song loseSound,
        Song startSound,
        SoundEffect badCollSound,
        SoundEffect goodCollSound,
        SoundEffect popUp
        )
    {
        this.winSound = winSound;
        this.loseSound = loseSound;
        this.startSound = startSound;
        this.badCollSound = badCollSound;
        this.goodCollSound = goodCollSound;
        this.popUp = popUp;
    }


    public void PlayGameMusic(GameMusic effType)
    {
        switch (effType)
        {
            case GameMusic.GameWin:
                PlayMusic(winSound);
                break;
            case GameMusic.GameLose:
                PlayMusic(loseSound);
                break;
            case GameMusic.GameStart:
                PlayMusicRepeat(startSound);
                break;
        }
    }


    public void PlayLevelEffect(LevelEffect effType)
    {
        switch (effType)
        {
            case GameMusic.BadCollision:
                PlayEffect(badCollSound);
                break;
            case GameMusic.GoodCollision:
                PlayEffect(goodCollSound);
                break;
            case GameMusic.PopUp:
                PlayEffect(popUp);
                break;
        }
    }


    public void PlayEffect(SoundEffect sound)
    {
        sound.Play();
    }


    public bool CheckAlreadyPlayingMusic()
    {
        return MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Playing;
    }


    public void PlayMusic(Song song)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = false;
    }


    public void PlayMusicRepeat(Song song)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(song);
        MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
    }


    public void StopMusic()
    {
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
    }


    public void PauseMusic()
    {
        MediaPlayer.Pause();
    }


    public void ResumeMusic()
    {
        MediaPlayer.Resume();
    }


    public void ChangeVolume(float volume)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Volume = volume;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have `SoundEffect` class with "Load" procedure where load all sounds into public variables from `LoadContent`. so everywhere i need some sound i just call `SoundEffect.Kaboom.Play()` ... something like that.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I use a `AudioManager` class and when I need a sound I simply call `audioManager.PlayEffect(effectName)`, where `effectName` is an enum.

Comment: I got this error when trying this out
Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Content.get'

Comment: @EvanKohilas update the code in your question so I can see what you are doing.

Comment: @pinckerman user Kai Hartmann helped me solve this, I am sorry for the late reply but I was finishing school and I am now on holidays. Your method seems very interesting  and more cleaner, however Kai's method was much simpler and a quicker fix. Are you able to provide me an example of code with your audio manager class in it? I would much appreciate having a look at your code and having a try at it myself :)

Comment: It looks very interesting, I only started learning a while ago so its still abit difficult for me to understand but either way, thanks again!